# Apply styling to all link elements

Tags: css, wordpress

I am not sure if that is possible in wordpress, but I need to style all `<a herf=""></a>` elements in theme by adding code in style.css.

The styling needs to apply for all links except for links in buttons and in header section where menu is placed. Code below doesnt work

```
a:link {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:active{
  color: purple;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: "Code below doesn't work" - Does it style _any_ of links correctly?

Comment: It styles all links, even the wp dashboard :) but I need to make exceptions for header and buttons...

Comment: Ok, see my answer and fiddle. I think it works. You will have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS probably doesn't work because your WordPress theme already contains some CSS rules for links, so it takes precedence over your rules.

You need to be more specific in the elements you target, for example:

```css
a {}
a.some-class {} /* more specific */
body a.some-class {} /* even more specific */
```

> **Specificity** is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied. […] Specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration, determined by the number of each selector type in the matching selector. When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element.

— [MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Also, if you're using a child theme, make sure that your stylesheets are getting enqueued after your (parent) theme's stylesheet.

Setting the parent theme styles as a dependency of your child theme's stylesheet will ensure that the child theme stylesheet loads after it.

The official [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#3-enqueue-stylesheet) contains this example:

```php
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
```

As for this part of your question:

> The styling needs to apply for all links except for links in buttons and in header section where menu is placed.

You can use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class, also known as the *negation pseudo-class*, to exclude your buttons and header section.

This would look like this:

```
:not(button) a, :not(header) a {
  /* links styling rules */
}
```

assuming you want to target all `<button>` and `<header>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use some JavaScript ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5bjs8z0o/2/)).

```
const anchors = Array.from(document.querySelector('a'))
for (const anchor of anchors) {
  if (!anchor.closest('button') && !anchor.closest('.header-class-name')) {
    anchor.classList.add('my-link')
  }
}
```

This will work if you know the class name of the header or menu.

And use this CSS.

```
.my-link {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.my-link:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.my-link:active{
  color: purple;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```